# if an option is selected, hide a div

Tags: jquery

i want to hide a div with class 'picture' if selected is User Profile ,on page load

```
<div id="edit-type-wrapper">
 <select>
   <option value="albums">Album</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="uprofile">User Profile</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class='picture'>
</div>
```

Comment: on the change of the option ? what have you tried ?

Comment: just needed on document ready :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    if($('#edit-type-wrapper select').val() == 'uprofile'){ //'.val()'
           $('.picture').hide();
       }


    $('#edit-type-wrapper select').change(function(){
       if($(this).val() == 'uprofile'){ //'.val()'
           $('.picture').hide();
           return true;
       }
       $('.picture').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
$('#edit-type-wrapper').change(function()
{
      if($(this).val() =="uprofile"){
          $('.picture').hide();
      }
      else{ 
          $('.picture').show();

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#edit-type-wrapper select').change(function() {
     if($(this).val() == "uprofile"){
       $('.picture').hide();
     } else {
       $('.picture').show();
     }
  });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/YpVVC/1/

Answer (score 0):

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9fyJZ/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit-type-wrapper").find('select').change(function() {
        var $val = $(this).val();

        if($val === 'uprofile'){
            $('.picture').hide();
        }else{
            $('.picture').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## update : found the solution

```
<script>
if($("#edit-type-wrapper").find("option:selected").val() == "uprofile") {
  $(".picture").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Note your solution will only hide the div on page load, and will not later show the div if the selection changes. If you want the div to hide and show dynamically after page load depending on the state of the selection, @Guarav's answer shows how to do that. Incidentally, Guarav's answer also hides the div on load as you asked about. I'm curious: any reason you didn't accept his answer?

Comment: didnt checked his solution as i needed specific answer..ie for page load , other functionality was already done that time